# Tor client node ignores `set_config` from Stem

Tags: configuration, client, stem, settings

I was doing some experiments for a project on a Tor test network. I used Chutney to set up a small network and Stem to control one of the client nodes in the network. Because I made some changes on a relay node, I wanted to set up a circuit containing that node and run some quick experiments. My changes made the relay node run much slower, so I also need to change some default timeout settings.

I used the following code to set up a new circuit:

```
circuit_id = controller.new_circuit(path=["test009r", "test008r"], purpose='general', await_build=True)
```

The new circuit contains two relay nodes. I made some changes on the `test009r` node.
Circuit building failed at runtime because:

```
Circuit failed to be created: CHANNEL_CLOSED
```

I believe it was because of some timeout, so I configured the client node:

```
controller.set_conf("MaxCircuitDirtiness", "60000")
controller.set_conf("LearnCircuitBuildTimeout", "0")
controller.set_conf("CircuitBuildTimeout", "60000")
controller.set_conf("CircuitStreamTimeout", "60000")
```

I tried to set large timeout windows, but it seemed like Tor just ignored them, because I still got the same error.
I also tried:

```
controller.signal(stem.Signal.HUP)
```

after `set_conf` to "refresh" the configuration of the client node.
When running `controller.get_conf_map`, I was able to confirm that those configurations did change.
This part of the info.log might be relevant:

```
Jul 16 22:29:55.295 [info] circuit_build_times_set_timeout(): Set buildtimeout to low value 485.535223ms. Setting to 1500ms
Jul 16 22:29:55.417 [info] circuit_build_times_set_timeout(): Based on 164 circuit times, it looks like we don't need to wait so long for circuits to finish. We will now assume a circuit is too slow to use after waiting 2 seconds.
Jul 16 22:29:55.428 [info] circuit_build_times_set_timeout(): Circuit timeout data: 1500.000000ms, 60000.000000ms, Xm: 75, a: 0.861692, r: 0.170732
Jul 16 22:29:55.522 [info] circuit_build_times_filter_timeouts(): We had 28 timeouts out of 164 build times, and filtered 0 above the max of 60000
```

But I am not sure how to parse them. For example, from Tor's documentation, 60000 should be in seconds, but not ms?

Comment: Are you sure that those log lines were from after you changed the config? The `circuit_build_times_set_timeout()` function should exit immediately if `LearnCircuitBuildTimeout` is 0. The default `CircuitBuildTimeout` is 60000 ms, so this number should be expected if it's before you changed the config setting.

Comment: Also a `CHANNEL_CLOSED` message means that this probably isn't a timeout problem. The circuit build is failing because the network connection between the two relays is closing. How soon after tying to build a circuit do you get this error?

Comment: Thanks @Steve. Your comments made me realize I was looking at logs of a wrong node (i.e., the relay node); I should instead check the client node log to see if its settings have changed. I removed all my changes and just wanted to check if `set_conf` works. Here is what I saw from the client log: `Jul 17 03:01:39.064 [info] options_validate_cb(): You disabled LearnCircuitBuildTimeout, but didn't specify a CircuitBuildTimeout. I'll pick a plausible default.` Although I did later specify, I saw no more logs regarding CircuitBuildTimeout (or CircuitStreamTimeout, MaxCircuitDirtiness). Any guess?

Comment: You should use [`set_options()`](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.control.Controller.set_options) instead to set multiple related settings at the same time.

Comment: Will do @Steve. Re: `CHANNEL_CLOSED`. The script hung for a couple of minutes before I received the error. I seem to have a hard time finding any relevant logs in the client or the relay nodes. Are there any keywords I should be searching for in the logs, say, if the relay node is not reachable or the connection is closed? Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't think I have any suggestions, these types of things are difficult to debug. What I usually do is just enable debug logging for the relays and client using Chutney, and work my way through them using the timestamps hoping to find something that looks off. Usually it's helpful to follow along in the code at the same time. The client should log each time it receives a CREATED or RELAY{EXTENDED} reply cell (I forget the exact log message), so it might be useful to watch for those as well to know how far the circuit creation gets.